# getText() returns empty string after sendKeys()

Tags: java, selenium

I have a class with the following public instance variable

```
@FindBy(id="titleInput")
public WebElement titleInputBox;
```

Then I use page factory in the constructor to initialize it on every use

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

In my test case for this page, I use the following code to test whether the text I sent is actually getting set in the field ...

```
subtitleInputBox.sendKeys("Test");
subtitleInputBox.getText();
```

and I get empty string

any idea why this happens ... I think it works fine if `driver.findElement()` is used directly without `@FindBy` and `PageFactory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually [`WebElement.getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) returns the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) **innerText of this element**, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace while you need input box element value attribute text.

FYI input box element stores the text which you are trying to set using [`WebElement.sendKeys()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) into their attribute name `value` instead of inner text.

So you should try using [`WebElement.getAttribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) which to be used to get the value of a the given attribute of the element.

Here you need to implement [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) also to determine whether element value has been successfully set or not using [`ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementValue-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.String-) as below :-

```
subtitleInputBox.sendKeys("Test");

//Now wait until value has been set into element 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(subtitleInputBox, "Test"));

//Now get the element value
subtitleInputBox.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the text out of an input box like text or textarea you need to use the `getAttribute("value")` method. `getText()` works for tags like div, span etc etc.

```
subtitleInputBox.getAttribute("value");
```